# Change polygon color on click with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a gray layer to display multiple polygons on the Mapbox map. I'm attempting to change the color of only one of them when the user clicks on it to display the "selected" the polygon. I don't want interaction, that's why I'm not using the Draw library, just to show the selected polygon.

[image]

Is there any way to do it in just one layer?? I tried adding a `boolean` property called "selected" to each polygon property, but I didn't achieve to update the layer.

```
// Define polygons with properties
var features = [];
areas.forEach(area => features.push(turf.polygon(area.polygon, { id_area: area.id_area, name: area.name, selected: 'false' })));
features = turf.featureCollection(features);

map.on('load', function () {
    // Add polygons to map
    map.addSource('areas', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': features
    });
    // Layer settings
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'polygons',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'areas',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
                'match',
                ['get', 'selected'],
                'true', '#64bdbb', // if selected true, paint in blue
                '#888888' // else paint in gray
            ],
            'fill-opacity': 0.4
        },
        'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']]
    });
}); 
// Click on polygon
map.on('click', 'polygons', function (e) {
    if(e.features.length) {
        var feature = e.features[0];
        if (feature.properties.id_area == id) {
            feature.properties.selected = 'true';
        } else {
            feature.properties.selected = 'false';
        }


        // How can I update the layer here to repaint polygons????


    }
});
```

Comment: Please cut/paste your answer (SOLUTION) from the area reserved for questions into the area reserved for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should work. It's very similar to this hover effect tutorial:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-interactive-hover-effects-with-mapbox-gl-js/

```
map.on('load', function () {
    // Add polygons to map
    map.addSource('areas', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': features
    });
    // Layer settings
    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'polygons',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'areas',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
                'case',
                ['boolean',['feature-state', 'clicked'], true],
                '#64bdbb', // if selected true, paint in blue
                '#888888' // else paint in gray
            ],
            'fill-opacity': 0.4
        },
        'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']]
    });
}); 

var polygonID = null;

map.on('click', 'polygon', (e) => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  if (e.features.length > 0) {
    if (polygonID) {
      map.removeFeatureState({
        source: "polygon",
        id: polygonID
      });
    }

    polygonID = e.features[0].id_area;

    map.setFeatureState({
      source: 'polygon',
      id: polygonID,
    }, {
      clicked: true
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that, but it seems ``e.features[0].id`` it's undefined, don't know why...

Comment: I'm guessing that it's because your feature doesn't have an "id" field, so it's giving you undefined. If you use "id_area" like you have in your code, that should fix that.

Comment: But the "id" field shouldn't be automatically created when adding the polygons sources on the map??

Comment: In your code you specify the id_area field: areas.forEach(area => features.push(turf.polygon(area.polygon, { id_area: area.id_area, name: area.name, selected: 'false' })));

Comment: Yea, I fixed that... Thank you!! But anyway, ``setFeatureState to clicked: true`` doesn't make any styling change on the layer. Should I configure somehow the layer?

Comment: I've added the map load to the answer. That should show how the boolean case styling should be formatted.

Comment: I added some little changes to your solution to make it work. You can see them on my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104161/discussion-between-nash-and-mattm).

Answer (score 1):

Following @MattM's answer and this [tutorial](https://blog.mapbox.com/going-live-with-electoral-maps-a-guide-to-feature-state-b520e91a22d) I finally made it work.

```
map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('areas', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': features,
        'generateId': true // From the tutorial, we must generate ids with the generateId option
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'polygons',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'areas',
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': [
                'case',
                ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'clicked'], false], // Set this to false
                '#64bdbb',
                '#888888'               ],
            'fill-opacity': 0.4
        },
        'filter': ['==', '$type', 'Polygon']
    });
}); 

map.on('click', 'polygons', function (e) {
    if (e.features.length > 0) {
        if(typeof polygonID === 'number') { // Need to change this
            map.removeFeatureState({
                source: "areas",
                id: polygonID
            });
        }

        polygonID = e.features[0].id; // Get generated ID

        map.setFeatureState({
            source: 'areas',
            id: polygonID,
        }, {
            clicked: true
        });
    }
});
```